# Distributed cache with huge objects ~1-2GB

Tags: caching, memcached, distributed

I have a need to stream a huge dataset, around 1-2GB, but only on demand when they explore the data. For example, if they don't explore parts of the data, I don't want to send it out.

So now, I have a solution that effectively returns JSON only for things they need. The need for a cache arises because these 1-2GB objects are actually constructed in memory from a file or files on disk, so the latency is ~30 seconds if you have to read the file to return this data.

How do I manage such a cache? Basically I think the solution is something like ZooKeeper or such where I store the physical machine name which holds the cache and then forward my rest request to that.

Would you guys also consider this to be the right model? I wonder what kind of checks will I have to do such that if the node that has the cache goes down, I can still fullfil the request without an error, but higher latencies.

Has anybody developed such a system? All the solutions out there are for seemingly small rows or objects.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/golang/groupcache is used for bigger things, but although it's used by http://dl.google.com, I'm not sure how it would do with Multi-gigabyte objects.

On the other hand, HTTP can do partial transfers and will be very efficient at that. Take a look ar Varnish, or Nginx.